# Is turning off the engine when stopped at traffic lights bad for the car?

Tags: engine, starter, carburetor

What (if any) mechanical issues will be caused if a person regularly turns off their engine while stopped e.g. a traffic lights?

Assuming regular production gasoline-only (non-hybrid) cars as they are currently made.  (since hybrids already do this).

Comment: This question - how people feel about some issue x - is off-topic here. This isn't a discussion board, and this site looks for declarative answers, not opinions. You can read more about what's OK and what isn't in the [Help pages](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I voted to close.

Comment: Don't forget that in Germany for many years you have been legally obliged to turn off the engine at lights.  Leaving the car idling gets you a fine.

Comment: IDK if it is true that the biggest stress on the cam belt is when starting the engine. If so, frequent stop/start will shorten its life. I disabled the stop/start on my (German engined) car because it was dangerous: would cut the engine mid-manoeuvre leaving no power steering. But I am still able to stop the engine by the time honoured method of turning off the ignition key.

Comment: I've adjusted the question to make it appropriate and answerable here.  Note that a "promotional element" has been removed, if that's a deal-breaker, then your question will simply be deleted.

Comment: I thought pretty much every car - hybrid or not - does that now?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yep, that makes it OK IMO. Close vote retracted. Even if such behavior is common (or even mandated), and designed-for by manufacturers, it still might cause mechanical issues.